# Simulate enter keypress with KeypressEvent()

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

How would I simulate the enter key being hit on a webpage by using KeyboardEvent(). All of the older questions I see use deprecated things according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent and they do not work in chrome. Using `new KeyboardEvent` works but it does not actually execute the event in the browser

Comment: [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) deprecated? Since when?

Comment: Have you actually read the docs? https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/ doesn't indicate any deprecation (unless you mean in Windows...)

Comment: @Teemu sorry meant to say that most the things used are deprecated and using dispatchEvent does not work in the latest chrome browser.

Comment: What is the latest Chrome version? [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/s8zx67my/) in version 56.0.2924.87.

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery solution according to the [jQuery - Event()](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

```
$('#targetElement').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {which: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The key code for enter is 13 so here is the code.

```
<body onkeypress="runThis(event)">

 function runThis(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                console.log("You clicked enter");
            }
        }

</body>
```

I hope this one solve your issue

Comment: Your code doesn't trigger the event. It only checks if the user have pressed the enter key.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. I just want to trigger the event not handle it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically is this the one which your are looking for